# Python Scrapy can't get pseudo class ":not()"

Tags: python, css-selectors, scrapy

It's OK to write

```
content.css('.text>p::text').extract()
```

But

```
content.css('.text:not(.text .text)>p::text').extract()
```

will not work.
It tells me:

```
SelectorSyntaxError: Expected ')', got <S ' ' at 15>
```

Yes, the 15th letter in the '.text:not(.text .text)>p::text' is ' ', but how can I express this meaning without using a ' '?

## Update

There are nested `<div class='text'>`s, I want to extract all the `<p>`s right beneath the first `<div class='text'>`.

For example:

```
<div class='text comment'>
    <strong>abc</strong>
    <span>def</span>
    <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
    <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
    <div class='text sub_comment'>
        <strong>lst</strong>
        <span>lll</span>
        <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
        <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get texts in the first two `<p>`. I can't use `.comment` and `.sub_comment` to distinguish them because they change from case to case and are not definitely `comment` in the outside and `sub_comment` in the inner tag.

Comment: your question seems unclear to me, can you give use sample markup you're trying to match with this selector?

Comment: @PawelMiech I updated the question. I solved this problem using xpath. Do you think there's a css solution?

Answer (score 3):

How about trying [nth-child(1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)?

So your css would be:

```
".text:nth-child(1)>p"
```

In Scrapy:

```
In [54]: from scrapy import Selector

In [55]: a
Out[55]: u"<div><div class='text comment'>    <strong>abc</strong>    <span>def</span>    <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>    <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>    <div class='text sub_comment'>        <strong>lst</strong>        <span>lll</span>        <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>        <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>    </div></div></div>"

In [56]: sel = Selector(text=a)

In [57]: sel.css(".text:nth-child(1)>p::text").extract()
Out[57]: [u'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx']
```

There is nice explanation and demo of nth-child in [this tutorial here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) (scroll down to paragraph 22).